# How to combine/merge lists of strings in Python with the same length keeping common values?

Tags: python, string, list

I have 3 lists of strings in Python with the same length. I would like to combine/merge them in a way that in those positions where there is an “X”, the “X” will prevail over the “O”s.
Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Input lists:

```
L1 = ['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']

L2 = ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O']

L3 = ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Desired output:

```
desired_list = ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "Any suggestion on how to achieve this?" Functionally, you have at least two questions: how to compare the lists element-wise, and how to check whether there is an `x` in a given group of elements. You should try to write code yourself and explain where you get stuck. At the very least, talk through your intended approach to solving the problem, and explain what you do and don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Zip the lists together and use `in` to check if there are any Xs.

```
result = ["X" if "X" in t else "O" for t in zip(L1, L2, L3)]
```

Or you could even use the fact that `"X" > "O"`:

```
result = [max(t) for t in zip(L1, L2, L3)]
```

If doing a lot of work like this, consider using `numpy` or `pandas`. In `numpy` you could do:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([L1, L2, L3])
result = np.where((m == "X").any(axis=0), "X", "O")
```

or

```
result = np.array([L1, L2, L3], dtype=object).max(axis=0)
```